# SSMS Restore Database - Trail Log and Server Connections Options are Greyed Out

Tags: database, ssms, database-backups, ssms-18

I am trying to restore a database from a backup in SSMS. I right-click on the database, select "Tasks", Restore, and Database. I then select Device and select my backup file as normal.

On the Options tab, though, I noticed that the "Trail-Log Backup" and "Server Connections" options are inaccessible, regardless of which "Recovery State" I select in the "Restore Options" - screenshot below.

[image]

What could I be missing here?

I have reviewed this page in Microsoft's documentation, but no lightbulbs just yet:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-database-options-page?view=sql-server-ver16

Apologies if this questions has already been asked/answered - I didn't see it on here when I searched, but could also be that I'm not using the right terms. Still very novice at this.

Thanks!

Comment: You aren't overwriting a database, so what tail are you expecting to backup here?

Comment: If you're restoring the backup to a different server or as a differently named database, these options are not relevant, why do you want to be able to select them?